# Use pipe() and fdopen() to pass data from Python script to C++ application in Windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, mingw, cross-platform

We have some Linux/macOS application, which can communicate with outer world by passing file descriptor and reading data from it. Usually this is done to pass stdin/stdout descriptors, however we use pipe() and this works pretty well. Except MinGW/Windows.
What would be the recommended way of doing the same job under the Windows? Pass the whole file handle, or there are good ways to simulate small-int-like descriptor?

Comment: Your C++ application uses `pipe` and `fdopen`? If so, in Windows you can use `CreateProcess` and initialize the `STARTUPINFO` struct with file handles for stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: @TedLyngmo actually C++ application uses fdopen() and Python script feeds it with file descriptor number, obtained by os.pipe() call. So stdin/stdout/sterr approach will not work the desired way.

Comment: Ah... assuming the python side is ok, would the Windows [_fdopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fdopen-wfdopen?view=vs-2019) work? Or, you don't even get access to the file descriptor?

Comment: TedLyngmo: I receive fd = 3 from the Python, and attempt to open it fails with EBADF. 
@ErykSun thanks for the details! We use Python 2.7.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks again. Got a direction to search for explanation and got over this, which tells a lot: https://bugs.python.org/issue32865

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks again! Actually your comment should be transferred to answer. However, I managed to make this to work in sample C code (just to make sure I'm not missing anything), while still struggling with Python implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, C file descriptors are inherited in the process [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) record in the reserved fields `cbReserved2` and `lpReserved2`. The protocol is undocumented, but the source is distributed with Visual C++. C functions that use this feature include the [`_[w]spawn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=vs-2019) family of functions and [`[_w]system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019). (The `[_w]system` function, however, is not generally useful in this regard because only the immediate cmd.exe process inherits the parent's file descriptors. CMD does not pass them on to child processes.)

In Python 2.7, `os.pipe` is implemented by calling [`CreatePipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe), which returns non-inheritable file handles for the read and write ends of the pipe. These handles are then manually wrapped with inheritable file descriptors via [`_open_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=vs-2019), but the underlying OS handle is still non-inheritable. To work around this, duplicate the file descriptor via `os.dup`, which internally duplicates an inheritable file handle, and then close the source file descriptor. For example:

```
pread, pwrite = os.pipe()
pwrite_child = os.dup(pwrite)
os.close(pwrite)
```

Python's `subprocess` module is usually the preferred way to create a child process. However, we can't use `subprocess` in this case because it doesn't support inheriting file descriptors via `STARTUPINFO` (*). Here's an example that uses [`os.spawnv`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.spawnv) instead:

```
rc = os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT, 'path/to/spam.exe', ['spam', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```

---

(*) It's an awkward situation that Windows Python internally uses the C runtime file API (e.g. `_wopen`, `_read`, `_write`), but in places fails to support C file descriptors. It should bite the bullet and use the Windows file API directly with OS file handles, then it would at least be consistent.

Comment: Managed code to work using this approach. Additional part of problem was Python, compiled with MSYS/MinGW - it didn't work at all, while Windows Python installation worked well. lpReserved2 of MSYS/MinGW version had different data.